# Why do two ways of defining properties in C# have different results?

Tags: c#

Two ways to defining properties in C#

```
public class Program {

    public static bool[] Property1 => new bool[1];
    public static bool[] Property2 { get; } = new bool[1];

    public static void Main() {

        Property1[0] = true;
        Property2[0] = true;

        Console.WriteLine($"{Property1[0]} {Property2[0]}");

        Console.ReadLine();

    }

}
```

These two ways have different results

> False True

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public static bool[] Property1 => new bool[1];
```

Here you define a getter that is executed every time you read the property, so you return a new bool[] every time. And the default value of the one element in that array is *false*.

```
public static bool[] Property2 { get; } = new bool[1];
```

Here you initialize the value of the property just once, after that you return the same array every time, including the value that you set it to.

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

`public static bool[] Property=>new bool[1]` gets translated to something like:

```
public static bool[] Property()
{
  return new bool[1];
}
```

Whereas when you define a `auto property` like:

`public static bool[] Property2 { get; } = new bool[1];`
It is translated to:

```
public static bool [] property=new bool[1];
public static bool[] Property
{
  get
  {
      return property;
  }
}
```

You can see that in the first case you would always get the array reinitialized on every call.

**P.S** In the second case I am not 100%  sure internally where the default initialization takes place (either in the private field or in the `setter`).